# Sum and List in the same groupby Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to make a simple variable where I do the df_dates and df_sum in the same time. Is it possible? 
I mean, I need a sum for all my cells but for 'Date' I need an array (list)

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('global.csv')
df_dates = df.groupby(['Io Id'])['Date'].apply(list)
df_sum = df.groupby(['Advertiser ID', 'Campaign Id', 'C Goal', 'C Goal KPI', 'C Goal KPI Value', 'Insertion Order', 'Io Id', 'IO Pacing', 'IO Pacing Rate', 'IO Pacing Amount', 'IO Goal Type', 'IO Goal Value', 'IO Budget Type', 'IO_Bud_Imp', 'IO_Bud_Start', 'IO_Bud_End'])['Impressions', 'Clicks', 'Click Rate (CTR)', 'Total Conversions', 'Post-Click Conversions', 'Post-View Conversions', 'Revenue (Adv Currency)'].sum()

df_dates = df_dates.to_frame()
df_first = pd.merge(df_dates, df_sum, on='Io Id')
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Since the content of `golbal.csv` is unknown. It is hard to visualize what are want to do. Can you show a simple small [MCVE] from your data?

Comment: At a glance it looks like it wouldn't be possible because you appear to have 2 different levels of aggregation

Answer (score 0):

Try using `agg` with a dictionary on how to aggregate each column:

Create a list of columns to be summed:

```
collist = ['Impressions', 'Clicks', 'Click Rate (CTR)', 'Total Conversions', 'Post-Click Conversions', 'Post-View Conversions', 'Revenue (Adv Currency)']
```

Create a dictionary from this list:

```
dsum = {i:'sum' for i in collist}
```

Now add 'Date' to this dictionary with a function list

```
dsum['Date'] = list
```

Now, use groupby with agg:

```
collist.append('Date')
df.groupby(['Advertiser ID', 'Campaign Id', 'C Goal', 'C Goal KPI', 
            'C Goal KPI Value', 'Insertion Order', 'Io Id', 'IO Pacing', 
            'IO Pacing Rate', 'IO Pacing Amount', 'IO Goal Type', 
            'IO Goal Value', 'IO Budget Type', 'IO_Bud_Imp', 'IO_Bud_Start', 
            'IO_Bud_End'])[collist].agg(dsum)
```